# Master/Detail in TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I've been working on this app for a while now and have changed tactic every time someone suggests something. Good for learning curb but not good for getting my app finished. I thought to ask a question (big ask I know) based on my current obstacles…

1. Passing values to and from ViewModels (Master/Multiple Child)
2. Setting up validation between VM’s in tabcontrol
3. Couple “Save Button” with validation on all VM’s
4. Save button on parent to save data from Parent and Child VM’s

I’m running a SQLite database at backend. I’ve got the gist of the coding involved in  using this. I’ve managed to get Caliburn Micro implemented and can setup my Views/ViewModels accordingly.
What I can’t seem to get my head around is how to communicate between VM’s and perform various actions on data/fields/screens.

Application description:
A main view that has data bound from SQLite db. Along with main view I have TabControl  that has various UserControls with their own VM. I need user to populate/edit data on each TabItem. Also need to implement Validation on various fields etc. and tie all data back to parent “Save” routine. I’ve found independent examples of each of these, but every one of them seem disjointed in how they are implemented and none show beginning to end coding.

I’ve included a [skeleton example](http://1drv.ms/1F66Tol) of what I’ve done. Pointers in better ways of doing things are more than welcome, but most of all how do I tie everything up?
Could anyone point me to any sample applications that incorporate multiple VM’s on TabControl including validation and comms between VM’s etc?

PS. Not looking for anyone to write my code for me... but I still consider myself a newbie and need all the help I can get.

Comment: You're asking way too many things at once, you're better off chopping this up in additional questions that revolve around a single problem each and provide small code examples and/or the desired result for each problem. At this current state, this question could be flagged as _too broad_.

Comment: I think you probably want to look at the `EventAggregator` and `IHandle` interface; I've mentioned it briefly in some other answers (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512461/caliburn-micro-composing-views-from-multiple-views-usercontrols-customcontrol/20530040#20530040, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23203379/advice-on-views-navigation-using-caliburn-micro-mvvm-wpf/23254345#23254345). I think the actual Caliburn examples may give you enough information, but I could try and dig out some code where I've done something very similar to what you're after if not.

Comment: Thanks for that Chris... would it be to much trouble to dig that example up?

Comment: Sure thing, I'll try and find it this week when I get a chance, I believe it will try and use a database I now longer have available, but the structure may still be of use.

Comment: @Chris... I've been looking and have run up the tutorial (http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/2/1/caliburn-micro-part-4-the-event-aggregator/), but all fails when I implement Jasons sample using CM 2.0.X...I think he is using 1.3.x or something. Are these features implemented differently? PS. The database hook is a good thing as my app is backended into an SQLite database... hoping your solution would show me a few things regarding DB integration etc.

Comment: Ah, I think my example is also using 1.3.x, the behaviour may have changed somewhat.

Comment: @Chris...Hi again....lol at this point in time I'll take whatever examples come my way. I managed to find a more up to date way of Jasons tutorial... I think on system.mike...so if you could still send I'll appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have anywhere I can upload the example? I'd rather not quite throw it into the public domain =D

Comment: I'm not sure if you can upload to my hotmail onedrive...else do you have onedrive I could tap into...

Comment: In the interest of just getting it done =D https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=67FF3A192E810386%21132 Be warned, I haven't looked at it in a good long while, and have just ripped out some proprietary info. It won't connect/work properly, but there might just be something in there you can use. Good Luck =D